# Install jupyter notebook offline without pip

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I need to install jupyter notebook in my computer without internet network.

I cannot install with anaconda with security problem.

I can use pip only with .whl files because I don't have any internet access with this computer.

I've downloaded notebook-master.zip file from https://github.com/jupyter/notebook

But I still cannot install jupyter notebook with this zip file.

Please help me install jupyter notebook.

Thx

Comment: Which file(s) do I need to dowlonad for Jupyter Notebooks? I don't seem to be able to find the master file you are referring to. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract zip file and run this command :

```
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --root=/
```

Or you can use this command

```
pip install .
```

Comment: still I have a problem. When I run the command, I get "Aborting implicit building of eggs. Use 'pip install .' to install from source."

Answer (score 0):

Pip has a download option. Not only for wheels, for everything that's pip installable.

Go into an empty folder on a computer that has the same operating
system as your offline computer and the same version of python

Then download all required libraries (do not forget pip itself), like

```
pip download pip
pip download jupyter
pip download jupyterlab
pip download pandas
pip download requests
...
```

move the folder content to a directory on the offline computer

```
pip install pip -U --no-index --find-links . 
pip install jupyter --no-index --find-links . 
pip install jupyterlab -U --no-index --find-links . 
...
```

If you get an error, because you forgot a library, download it, move it and continue.

And if you're on windows, you may need to download some libraries from [this collection](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) if those fail to install.

This will allow you to get a working jupyter installation with everything that's installable via pip.